# Requesting for JSON using Volley and serializing

Tags: java, android, json, android-volley

I have a JSON file placed in the server which describes one academic week schedule of a class. I have to request for it using Volley. Later I need to serialize the returned JSON object individually and create multiple events for that particular month.

But when I run the application, Volley returns onErrorResponse. When I try doing the same with Retrofit, it worked fine but the output is not as expected.

IT-3-2.json

```
 [{"schedule_of":"IT-3-2","day":"1","from_time":"09:55","to_time":"10:45","subject":"CC","details":"manasa"},
  {"schedule_of":"IT-3-2","day":"1","from_time":"10:45","to_time":"11:35","subject":"CC","details":"manasa"},
  {"schedule_of":"IT-3-2","day":"1","from_time":"11:35","to_time":"12:25","subject":"WT","details":"asha"},
  {"schedule_of":"IT-3-2","day":"1","from_time":"12:25","to_time":"13:15","subject":"WT","details":"asha"},
  {"schedule_of":"IT-3-2","day":"1","from_time":"14:15","to_time":"15:05","subject":"ACS lab","details":"gouthami"},
  {"schedule_of":"IT-3-2","day":"1","from_time":"15:05","to_time":"15:55","subject":"ACS lab","details":"gouthami"},
  {"schedule_of":"IT-3-2","day":"1","from_time":"15:55","to_time":"16:45","subject":"ACS lab","details":"gouthami"},
  {"schedule_of":"IT-3-2","day":"2","from_time":"09:55","to_time":"10:45","subject":"IPR","details":"samreen"},
  {"schedule_of":"IT-3-2","day":"2","from_time":"10:45","to_time":"11:35","subject":"IPR","details":"samreen"},
  {"schedule_of":"IT-3-2","day":"2","from_time":"11:35","to_time":"12:25","subject":"WT","details":"asha"},
  {"schedule_of":"IT-3-2","day":"2","from_time":"12:25","to_time":"13:15","subject":"WT","details":"asha"},
  {"schedule_of":"IT-3-2","day":"2","from_time":"14:15","to_time":"15:05","subject":"WT lab","details":"rajesh"},
  {"schedule_of":"IT-3-2","day":"2","from_time":"15:05","to_time":"15:55","subject":"WT lab","details":"rajesh"},
  {"schedule_of":"IT-3-2","day":"2","from_time":"15:55","to_time":"16:45","subject":"WT lab","details":"rajesh"},
  {"schedule_of":"IT-3-2","day":"3","from_time":"09:55","to_time":"10:45","subject":"DWDM","details":"shashikanth"},
  {"schedule_of":"IT-3-2","day":"3","from_time":"10:45","to_time":"11:35","subject":"DWDM","details":"shashikanth"},{"schedule_of":"IT-3-2","day":"3","from_time":"11:35","to_time":"12:25","subject":"OOAD","details":"madhukar"},{"schedule_of":"IT-3-2","day":"3","from_time":"12:25","to_time":"13:15","subject":"OOAD","details":"madhukar"},{"schedule_of":"IT-3-2","day":"4","from_time":"09:55","to_time":"10:45","subject":"STM","details":"harikrishna"},{"schedule_of":"IT-3-2","day":"4","from_time":"10:45","to_time":"11:35","subject":"STM","details":"harikrishna"},{"schedule_of":"IT-3-2","day":"4","from_time":"11:35","to_time":"12:25","subject":"OOAD","details":"shashikanth"},{"schedule_of":"IT-3-2","day":"4","from_time":"12:25","to_time":"13:15","subject":"OOAD","details":"shashikanth"},{"schedule_of":"IT-3-2","day":"4","from_time":"14:15","to_time":"15:05","subject":"DWDM","details":"shashikanth"},{"schedule_of":"IT-3-2","day":"4","from_time":"15:05","to_time":"15:55","subject":"DWDM","details":"shashikanth"},{"schedule_of":"IT-3-2","day":"5","from_time":"09:55","to_time":"10:45","subject":"IPR","details":"samreen"},{"schedule_of":"IT-3-2","day":"5","from_time":"10:45","to_time":"11:35","subject":"IPR","details":"samreen"},{"schedule_of":"IT-3-2","day":"5","from_time":"11:35","to_time":"12:25","subject":"STM","details":"harikrishna"},{"schedule_of":"IT-3-2","day":"5","from_time":"12:25","to_time":"13:15","subject":"STM","details":"harikrishna"},{"schedule_of":"IT-3-2","day":"5","from_time":"14:15","to_time":"15:05","subject":"CC","details":"manasa"},{"schedule_of":"IT-3-2","day":"5","from_time":"15:05","to_time":"15:55","subject":"CC","details":"manasa"}]
```

AsynchronousActivity.java

```
  @Override
public List<? extends WeekViewEvent> onMonthChange(int newYear, int newMonth) {

    visibleMonth = newMonth;
    visibleYear = newYear;
    Log.d(TAG, "month changed - "+newMonth);


    final String URL = "http://192.168.0.5/practice/schedule/jsons/IT-3-2.json";
    // Post params to be sent to the server
    HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
    params.put("token", "AbCdEfGh123456");

    JsonObjectRequest req = new JsonObjectRequest(URL,null /*new JSONObject(params)*/,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

                    Gson gson = new Gson();
                    VolleyLog.v("Response:%n %s", response);
                    makeWeeklyEvents((List<WeeklyEvent>) gson.fromJson(response.toString(),WeeklyEvent.class) );
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void  onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                    VolleyLog.e("Error: ", error.getMessage());

                }
    });

    // add the request object to the queue to be executed
    //AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(req);
    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    queue.add(req);

    // Return only the events that matches newYear and newMonth.
    List<WeekViewEvent> matchedEvents = new ArrayList<WeekViewEvent>();
    for (WeekViewEvent event : events) {
        if (eventMatches(event, newYear, newMonth)) {
            matchedEvents.add(event);
        }
    }
    return matchedEvents;

}

public void makeWeeklyEvents(List<WeeklyEvent> events){
    this.events.clear();
    for (WeeklyEvent event : events) {
       this.events.addAll(event.toWeekViewEvent());
       Log.d(TAG, "size of events : "+this.events.size());
    }
    getWeekView().notifyDatasetChanged();
}
```

weeklyEvent.java

```
public class WeeklyEvent {

    private static final String TAG = WeeklyEvent.class.getSimpleName();


    @Expose
    @SerializedName("subject")
    private String mName;
    @Expose @SerializedName("day")
    private int mDay;
    @Expose @SerializedName("from_time")
    private String mStartTime;
    @Expose @SerializedName("to_time")
    private String mEndTime;

    public String getName() {
        return mName;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.mName = name;
    }

    public int getDay() {
        return mDay;
    }

    public void setDay(int day) {
        this.mDay = day;
    }

    public String getStartTime() {
        return mStartTime;
    }

    public void setStartTime(String startTime) {
        this.mStartTime = startTime;
    }

    public String getEndTime() {
        return mEndTime;
    }

    public void setEndTime(String endTime) {
        this.mEndTime = endTime;
    }

    @SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat")
    public ArrayList<WeekViewEvent> toWeekViewEvent(){

        // Parse time.
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
        Date start = new Date();
        Date end = new Date();
        try {
            start = sdf.parse(getStartTime());
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            end = sdf.parse(getEndTime());
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // Initialize start and end time.
        Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
        // Create an week view event.
        ArrayList<WeekViewEvent> list = new ArrayList<WeekViewEvent>();
        // Create a WeekViewEvent holder
        WeekViewEvent weekViewEvent = new WeekViewEvent();

        for(int i= getFirstDay(1,AsynchronousActivity.visibleMonth,AsynchronousActivity.visibleYear) - getDay(); i<now.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);i+=7  ){

            Calendar startTime = (Calendar) now.clone();
            startTime.setTimeInMillis(start.getTime());
            startTime.set(Calendar.YEAR, AsynchronousActivity.visibleYear);
            startTime.set(Calendar.MONTH, AsynchronousActivity.visibleMonth);
            startTime.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, i);
            Calendar endTime = (Calendar) startTime.clone();
            endTime.setTimeInMillis(end.getTime());
            endTime.set(Calendar.YEAR, AsynchronousActivity.visibleYear);
            endTime.set(Calendar.MONTH, AsynchronousActivity.visibleMonth);
            endTime.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, i);

            // Set values into event.
            weekViewEvent.setName(getName());
            weekViewEvent.setStartTime(startTime);
            weekViewEvent.setEndTime(endTime);
            weekViewEvent.setColor(Color.GREEN);


            Log.d(TAG, "weekly event recieved : "+getName()+", time : "+weekViewEvent.getStartTime().getTimeInMillis() +" - "+weekViewEvent.getEndTime().getTimeInMillis());
            // Append WeekViewEvent to the list.
            list.add(weekViewEvent);
        }

        Log.d(TAG, "list is updating "+list.size()+" events.");

        return list;
    }

    public int getFirstDay(int day, int month, int year)
    {
        Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();
        cal.set(Calendar.DATE, day);
        cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, month);
        cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
        cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
        switch (cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK)) {

            case Calendar.MONDAY:
                return 0;
            case Calendar.TUESDAY:
                return 1;
            case Calendar.WEDNESDAY:
                return 2;
            case Calendar.THURSDAY:
                return 3;
            case Calendar.FRIDAY:
                return 4;
            case Calendar.SATURDAY:
                return 5;
            case Calendar.SUNDAY:
                return 6;
        }
        return -1;
    }

}
```

Running the application, it returns the follow Volley error: [screenshot of logcat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b18lF.png)

JSON file is accessible when I try the same URL link from the device browser.

When I tried doing the same with Retrofit, it successfully retrieved and processed the JSON but the output was not as expected.

```
        if (!calledNetwork) {
        RestAdapter retrofit = new RestAdapter.Builder()
                .setEndpoint("http://192.168.0.5")
                .build();
        MyJsonService service = retrofit.create(MyJsonService.class);
        service.listWeekEvents(this);
        calledNetwork = true;
```

MyJsonService.java

```
 public interface MyJsonService {

    @GET("/practice/schedule/jsons/IT-3-2.json")
    //http://192.168.0.5/practice/schedule/jsons/IT-3-2.json
    void listWeekEvents(Callback<List<WeeklyEvent>> weeklyEventsCallback);

}
```

The functionality is that, I need to duplicate the input event- JsonObject (it contains "day"-day_of_week which represents that event occurs every week on that day) to all that particular day of every week in one month.

```
        for(int i= getFirstDay(1,AsynchronousActivity.visibleMonth,AsynchronousActivity.visibleYear) - getDay(); i<now.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);i+=7  ){

            Calendar startTime = (Calendar) now.clone();
            startTime.setTimeInMillis(start.getTime());
            startTime.set(Calendar.YEAR, AsynchronousActivity.visibleYear);
            startTime.set(Calendar.MONTH, AsynchronousActivity.visibleMonth);
            startTime.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, i);
            Calendar endTime = (Calendar) startTime.clone();
            endTime.setTimeInMillis(end.getTime());
            endTime.set(Calendar.YEAR, AsynchronousActivity.visibleYear);
            endTime.set(Calendar.MONTH, AsynchronousActivity.visibleMonth);
            endTime.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, i);

            // Set values into event.
            weekViewEvent.setName(getName());
            weekViewEvent.setStartTime(startTime);
            weekViewEvent.setEndTime(endTime);
            weekViewEvent.setColor(Color.GREEN);


            Log.d(TAG, "weekly event recieved : "+getName()+", time : "+weekViewEvent.getStartTime().getTimeInMillis() +" - "+weekViewEvent.getEndTime().getTimeInMillis());
            // Append WeekViewEvent to the list.
            list.add(weekViewEvent);
        }
```

When the application is runned (on 14th Feb,2017), the events are shown only from 24th Feb,2017 - 28th Feb,2017. and that to all the duplicate events generated are shown in one day itself.

[screenshot of the application showing 26th Feb,2017 while runned with retrofit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J6Jq4.png)

I have been using alamkanak/Android-Week-View (link will be posted in answers section if wanted, as more then 2 links can't be posted for now) library to display the events.

Please, help me to solve this problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: link for alamkanak/Android-Week-View library :  https://github.com/alamkanak/Android-Week-View